# Alter array in loop and start at previously added item

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, loops, for-loop

I would like to loop an array and add to the array but then inside the loop make use of the previously added item. So I would like to loop 1,4,1 and add 0.5 between 1 and 4 and back to 1. So the final string or array would be:

1
1.5
2
2.5
3
3.5
4 etc

The problem is that I can add to index item but not add to THAT item in the loop. The first loop is 1 then I add 1.5 and the second loop should be 1.5 but the loop will be 4 instead.

```
base_string = '1,4,1';
base_string = base_string.split(',');

for (var i = 0; i < base_str.length; i++) {

// I add 1.5 to array and I want to use that the next loop, but the next loop is 4 instead

}
```

Comment: What happens after you reach 4?

Comment: I have to go back to 1 like: 3.5,3,2.5,2,1.5,1

Comment: I need to alter the string 1 4 1 to 1 1.5 2 etc with increment of 0.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let base_string = '1,4,1';
let base_array = base_string.split(',').map(i => +i);
let inc = 0.5; // the number to add in every step
let res = [];

let i = 0;

// Iterate till the last element is reached
while(i < base_array.length) {
  // Iterate till there is some difference between adjacent items
  while(Math.abs(base_array[i] - base_array[i+1]) > inc) {
    res.push(base_array[i]);
    
    if(base_array[i] < base_array[i+1]) base_array[i] += 0.5;
    else base_array[i] -= 0.5;
  }
  
  i++;
}

res.push(base_array[i-1]); // add the last element

console.log(res.join(' '));
```

Comment: Thanks but it gives me an error for i: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier: let i = 0, maxIter = 40, j = 0;

Comment: Sorry for the poor formatting, I've updated it with explanation in comments and it runs without any errors

Comment: Thank you vey much. I have spend all day on this, you saved my day, thanks again

Answer (score 2):

You could reduce the given array and fill the values by taking a value for incrementing or decrementing.

```js
var string = '1,4,1',
    result = string
        .split(',')
        .map(Number)
        .reduce((r, v) => {
            if (!r) return [v];
            let last = r[r.length - 1],
                delta = v > last ? 0.5 : -0.5;
            while (last + delta !== v) r.push(last += delta);
            r.push(v);
            return r;
        }, undefined);
   
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Wow that is some serious coding...thanks I will look into it later on

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this with two `for` loops and just maintain a `direction` variable to point the counters in the correct direction:

```js
let arr = [1, 4, 1]
let res = [arr[0]]
let step = 0.5
for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
  let direction = arr[i] > arr[i - 1] ? 1 : -1
  for (let j = (direction * arr[i - 1]) + step; j <= (direction * arr[i]); j += step) {
    res.push(j * direction)
  }
}
console.log(res)
```

Comment: Yep this works, thank you very much  ( it does give me double figures like 1, 1,  but I think I can figure that one out myself)

Comment: Right, @Youss, fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

this should work with any array.

```js
var base_string = '1,4,1,7,2';
base_string = base_string.split(',');

var new_string = []; 
for(var i=0; i<base_string.length-1; i++){
   if(base_string[i+1]>base_string[i]){
     for(var j=parseInt(base_string[i]); j<parseInt(base_string[i+1]); j+=.5){
         new_string.push((j))
     }
   }
  else  if(base_string[i+1]<base_string[i]){
     for(var j=parseInt(base_string[i]); j>=parseInt(base_string[i+1]); j-=.5){
         new_string.push((j))
     }
   }
}
console.log("new_string: "+new_string);
```

Comment: Thank you I will look into it but this is kinda over my head coding:)

Answer (score 1):

You can use "[reduce](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reduce.asp)" function like this:

```js
var base_string = '1,2,3,4';
base_string = base_string.split(',').reduce((a, v, i, ar) => {
  if (i === 1) {
    // an array is created using the first two values of original the array
    return [+a, +a + 0.5, +v, +v + 0.5];
  }
  // after index 2 you add an extra item +0.5
  a.push(+v);
  a.push(+v + 0.5);
  return a;
});
console.log(base_string);
```

This will give you the desired output:

```
[1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5]
```

Please note that a plus `(+)` symbol was added before every value, thats because they were string values so they needed to be casted to number.

Comment: Thank you I will look in to this (reduce is new to me)